# complex pipe with grep

Tags: xml, bash, grep

I'm sure there is lots of ways to do this in scripts. 
But I have a very specific use case in which why i need to do it like I'm doing.

Here is the use case.
I have a very large XML file and I'm finding the opening tags with the following command:

```
grep '<opening-tag>' -n ~/.dir/27-6-2019.xml | grep -Eo '^[^:]+'
```

This is working great and gets me the opening line of each tag.
To get the closing tag then all I need to do is decrement the line number by one and that works great in a script.

And then I run this command to get the xml content in the file (This is in the context of a script):

```
awk 'NR >= $startingIndex && NR <= ($closingIndex - 1) path-to-file
```

Once again this works great.

But what I'm wanting to achieve is something like the following:

```
grep '<open-tag>' -n ~/.dir/27-6-2019.xml | $STAT_INDEX=$(grep -Eo '^[^:]+') | if [$LAST_LINE]; awk 'NR >= $STAT_INDEX && NR <= ($LAST_LINE - 1) path-to-file > "dir/$STAT_INDEX.xml" | LAST_LINE=$STAT_INDEX
```

So basically as I'm doing the grep command and pipe then check if I've created the var $last_line var and then extract the xml obj and save it to another file. The reason I need last line is because on the first run I wont know the next starting index of the new object etc.

I'm not sure this is even possible. But I'm trying my best to do this in a one liner.

Thank you

If there are any other ways of doing this without having to rely on scripting or tools like terminal xml parsers (as i've tried them and they don't do what i need) then please let me know.

---------- grep logic - - - - - - - - - - - -

This gets all the open tag lines

```
grep '<open-tag>' -n ~/.dir/27-6-2019.xml
```

Pipe

Example valve: 12343:

```
$STAT_INDEX=$(grep -Eo '^[^:]+')
```

Set a var for the rest of the pipe process to access

Pipe

Then check is a var called last line has been set and if so the do this command to retrieve the xml obj from thr file and save it into its own file

```
if [$LAST_LINE]; awk 'NR >= $STAT_INDEX && NR <= ($LAST_LINE - 1) path-to-file > "dir/$STAT_INDEX.xml"
```

Pipe
Save the last line for the next grep process to process

```
LAST_LINE=$STAT_INDEX
```

Comment: It would be really helpful if you can share sample input and expected output.

Comment: Unfortunately i csnt but i dont really see how that would help. Its just badically ooening tag on line A n closing on line X or Y and thats my issue.

Comment: Would it help to break down my grep logic according to what im trying to do?

Comment: It would help: 1) to post a subset of your script, specifically the part where you have a problem; 2) to post an XML file, looking like the file you can't post but including similar input; 3) to show which output you want according to the input (see 2). This is the way SO is working. Otherwise, it will be hard to find people wanting to help you here.

Comment: This is just horrible. You're producing a hand-written parser for a small subset of XML. StackOverflow is full of questions from people trying to generate subsets of XML because other people have written programs that can only handle XML in a very specific format. Don't do it, use a proper XML parser.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use grep,sed,awk to handle a XML file. Use a XML parser. Post an abridged version of the XML file so you get a more reasonable responses.

Comment: I've already tried that. I have a program that has to use node. But node is way to slow at parsing the results. So if i try and run a long running command from node with shelljs it times out. Thats why I said I need a one liner working. Its much faster

Comment: And like i said before the structure of the xml is not relevant. <opening-tag></opening-tag> are on separate lines

Comment: in that case, why not sure us a sample input and desired output. Your question is too long and complex to understand. simplify the problem